# Calibrate Tensiometer

Tags: road-bike, wheels, tools, spokes, rims

I want to calibrate my Park Tool TM-1 for my weird spokes. I want to build a box with some kind of weight measuring device where a spoke can be put under 1600N of tension.

Rumours on other boards say that using a spring scale would yield wrong results, because the spring would move while measuring. I don't quite know if that is true or not?

Because I want a cheap solution, I don't want to spend 50 euros on a digital scale. Now I found a "butcher's scale" on ebay [here](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Hangewaage-Wildwaage-Metzgerwaage-Fischwaage-200Kg-1Kg-/310422350974?pt=Metzgereiausstattung&hash=item48469d2c7e#ht_4164wt_1058). Can I use that for my purpose, or will it also yield wrong tensiometer reults? I don't really understand the rational behind a spring scale messing up the results. Can someone shed some light on this?

Edit: [Here](http://www.mtb-news.de/forum/showthread.php?t=526067&page=2) is a picture and the discussion from some other board.

Comment: Hang the spoke (from something very strong) and apply 1600N of weight (359.7 pounds/163Kg).

Comment: That was my first idea, but I can't think of any place to mount the spoke, and I can't think of anything that weighs 160kg and is mountable to a spoke... :-(

Comment: Have you contacted Park Tool to see if they have the conversion table you need. If your spokes are unusual they may not have published the results

Comment: Did so now. See if they still answer today. But I still want to build this tool, just for the sake of it.

Comment: Well, you of course need brackets of some sort to grip the spoke ends.  One end would be a metal plate with a hole drilled the same size as a hub flange hole.  The other end would be a metal plate with a hole to accept a nipple, the plate bent in an L or U shape.  Hang it from a joist in your garage/basement/wherever.  (A swing set at a park would work.)  As for the weight, you're on your own.  (But there's no reason why a spring balance wouldn't work as well, if it's accurate enough for you.)

Comment: If a spoke nipple won't hold 1600N you're going to need a different way to anchor and adjust the end of the spoke. So the simple answer from Daniel is correct - I would get a short piece of steel strip, drill a 3mm hole in it, feed the spoke through, put the nipple on and hang my 160kg off it that way. But since cars and motorbikes have used spoked wheels, you may just need to upgrade to 4mm or 5mm spokes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're after here. Is your spoke type not available on Park's [TM-1 Tension Meter Conversion Table](http://www.parktool.com/assets/doc/product/TM-1_Table_3-21-14.pdf)? You're after relative spoke tension when you're measuring your tension as it's going to be different at different points from the hub to the rim. 1600N is well within the range of measurement for the TM-1 on almost all spoke types

Comment: Thanks, yes my spoke type is not listen. The aero spokes are only 1mm thick. Park Tool has only listen aero spokes starting from 1,5mm thickness. I want to know if I can use the scale from the link, or if that will somehow give my wrong results. Furthermore I would like to know why the results from spring based scales in combination with tensionmeters would give me a wrong result.

Comment: A spring based scale will be affected by the weight and/or tension added/subtracted by the tool itself. You need some method of applying a fixed amount of tension like a static weight or known force that is connected to a fixed object like a bench. Since a scale is variable when you apply the tension meter you'll not only be measuring the spoke's tension, you'll be measuring partial force applied and measured by the springs in the scale.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but the added tension to my spoke through the measuring tool should be neglectable compared to initial tension of 1600N. I don't think the bending of the spoke will have an great impact. I want to build something like discussed on the other board. Please click the link in my edited inital post (right at the bottom) and just quickly scroll through the thread to see the pictures. Then we might have the same understanding of what I want to do :-)

Comment: Yes, the goal is understood. The rig that has the digital meter is what you need to account for. There seems to be some way of measuring the tension with a scale and then locking it off, which takes any force yielded by the scale out of the equation for accurate calibration. What you're after is calibrating a measurement tool (TM-1) to a fixed standard. Having an additional variable (a scale) contained in the setup will yield an inaccurate calibration, which defeats the purpose of the measurement rig you are building. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, but not quite yet... I still think the forces are in no comparision. Imagine the whole costruction (scale, spoke and frame) are under 1600N of tension. If I now apply a small perpendicular force (maybe 25N through the TM-1) against the spoke, the measured weight may increase max. to 1625N, which is neglectable. The tensiometer only measures relativly how easy it is to bend the spoke sideways given a certain tension. Other components such as the scale don't get any perpendicular presure, and are therefore not part of the measurment. I still don't see a hazard for seriously wrong results

Comment: For this application, you're rig will probably be fine. You can also estimate from the chart that you're reading will possibly be around 3-5 on the deflection if the deflection pattern holds true. It seems to move 7 numbers for every .3mm difference for aluminum bladed spokes. Following that same logic you can estimate and compare vs. your rig.

Comment: Evey (non-exotic) scale made is either a spring scale or a balance scale.  Virtually all digital scales are spring scales.  It's just a question of how far the spring moves for a given weight.  In a way the simple (non-digital) spring scale is apt to be MORE accurate, since the applied force will increase less with a slight change in spoke length (due to the sideways deflection).  But in any event the change in spoke length is going to be negligible, relative to the accuracy of the gauge.